# how can I solve this in python?

Tags: python

Id codes at a company come in the form x-y-zzzzzz, where x is a digit and y is a letter and zzzzzz represents a string of 6 letters. Write a function which takes in a code as an input (e.g. 3-a-abaabb) and returns the zzzzzz part (e.g. abaabb).

I have no idea how to start and solve this question. any help would be much appreciated. My IDE is pycharm (solving python coding problems) I basically need to create a function which takes the code as an input and will return the last 6 letters

Comment: seems like a homework problem. show efforts ?

Comment: search for the keyword `rsplit`

Comment: The solution depends entirely on what you have learned so far in your course. It's probably doable with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.spit('-')` then search `count` in `code` with `repeat` is equal or not, like below:

```
def fnd_code(code):
    repeat, char, search =  code.split('-')
    return search.count(char) == int(repeat)

print(fnd_code('3-a-abaabb'))
print(fnd_code('4-a-abaabb'))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: there's a part 2 which i dont get how to answer: part 2: write a function which returns true if there are x amount of y's in the zzzzzz section (e.g. 3-a-abaabb would return true,  4-a-abaabb would return false)

Comment: @SreenithiSudhakar you want search `count char` in `code` you can see edited answer, this should be correct